# SharedArrayBuffer updates in Android Chrome 88 and Desktop Chrome 92

Tags: sharedarraybuffer

I need help to fix the following issue . While practicing with react app I got this msg in console:

[Deprecation] SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021. See https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/ for more details.
A
nyone experiencing this issue? And know  how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using SharedArrayBuffer yourself, the message might be caused by React. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20829 for more details. It's been fixed at React 17.0.2 but unfortunately it's not going to be backported to older versions.

The warning is to mitigate the trouble when SharedArrayBuffer is used after Chrome 92, but since [the availability of `window.SharedArrayBuffer` is checked in older React versions](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/e706721490e50d0bd6af2cd933dbf857fd8b61ed/packages/scheduler/src/SchedulerProfiling.js#L21), you will unlikely see the same issue.

The bottom line is, don't worry about the warning as far as you are confident that it is caused by React.